# Which is better performance wise in Angular: Object cloning or Object Creation?

Tags: json, angular, jsonschema

I want to convert JSON object to JSON schema. What I want to know is whether I should make a clone of JSON object and convert it into JSON schema or should I directly create a new JSON schema from JSON object. The JSON object will be a nested one with upto 30-40 levels.

Comment: You are basically asking if doing an extra step is better for performance. Obviously doing **extra work** is going to take **more time**. The question is, what benefit do you get by doing the cloning step, if any?

Comment: By cloning, I can iterate through the object and will have to modify less things.